# Input range handler doesn't render in Chrome

Tags: css, html, google-chrome, safari, webkit

I am working on a tool to preview fonts on a website. For this tool, I want to use `<input type="range" />` to change the font size in a textarea. Since I don't like the default WebKit rendering of the slider and the handler, I customized them using CSS. While the page renders fine in Safari,  Chrome does not display the slider handle (Sliders on other websites render fine, though). What do I have to change to make it work in Chrome as well?

The HTML

```
<input type="range" min="6" max="70" value="22" id="font-1-size" />
```

The CSS

```
.tester-option.font-size input
{
    -webkit-appearance: none !important;
    background: #cecece;
    height: 1px;
    width: 425px;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    margin-top: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.tester-option.font-size input::-webkit-slider-thumb
{
    -webkit-appearance: none !important;
    background: #666;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

You can find the live example here: http://fishnation.de/development/26plus/#test-font[image: render differences safari and chrome]

P.S. I am aware that there is jQuery UI, but I want to replace as few elements as possible.

Comment: I get the error "Modernizr is not defined" in Firebug. FF4 displays a 3px line that I can't interact with, Chrome just shows a line, and IE8 has nothing at all for the whole page. It works only in Safari for me, (and quite nicely).

Comment: Thanks for checking in Firefox and IE. Both Browsers do not yet support `<input type="range">`. Modernizr should work now.

Comment: Just took a look at your site, seems as though you've fixed it now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your selector. I used `#font-1-size::-webkit-slider-thumb`. This worked fine in chrome.

Comment: Thanks for testing. Which version of Chrome are you using? Changing the selector did not work for me (I'm on Chrome 11.0.696.68)...

Comment: I'm using the same version of Chrome. Take a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Gary/MgXYk/). You should be able to see it working?

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet you posted on jsfiddle. It works fine for me. I just updated the live example using your code. It still does not show the slider handle. Do you have an idea which CSS rule could cause this issue?